# ubuntu で時刻がずれる

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

VirtualBox に ubuntu18を入れて使ってるんですが時計がずれます

調べると ntp systemd-timesyncd timedatectl の３つぐらい方法が出てくるんですがどの方法がいいんでしょうか

ntp は入ってすらないようです

```
systemctl status ntp
Unit ntp.service could not be found.
```

systemd-timesyncd ははいってるようなんですが有効になりません
/usr/sbin/VBoxService was not met
ってでてるので vitrtualbox 上のゲストだと使えないんでしょうか

```
systemctl status systemd-timesyncd
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.d
           └─disable-with-time-daemon.conf
   Active: inactive (dead)
Condition: start condition failed at Sun 2020-04-05 03:11:11 JST; 10s ago
           └─ ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/VBoxService was not met
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)

 4月 05 03:05:52 moon systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Network Time Synchronization being ski
 4月 05 03:11:11 moon systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Network Time Synchronization being sk
```

timedatectl は実行すると RTC time というところに正常な時間が１つ表示されてるので
System clock synchronized をONにできれば解決しそうなんですがやり方がわかりません
NTP service: inactive
ってなってるので ntp をインストールして連携するものなんでしょうか

```
               Local time: 日 2020-04-05 03:06:30 JST
           Universal time: 土 2020-04-04 18:06:30 UTC
                 RTC time: 土 2020-04-04 17:51:36
                Time zone: Asia/Tokyo (JST, +0900)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

## 環境

ホスト: WIndows10 pro 64bit
Virtualbox 6.0
ゲスト: ubuntu 18? 確認の仕方が不明ですが uname 結果はこれです
`Linux 5.3.0-40-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 31 20:24:34 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(VirtualBox6.1.4とUbuntu18.04.4で試してみたところ全く同じ事象にはならなかったのでバージョンも明記するとよいかと思います)

Guest Additionsをインストールした場合Ubuntu標準の時刻同期の仕組みを止めて、VirtualBoxのやり方で(ホストOSから取得して)時刻同期する、というのは意図された挙動のようです。

[9.11.3. Tuning the Guest Additions Time Synchronization Parameters](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#changetimesync)(他):

> By default, Oracle VM VirtualBox keeps all sources of time visible to the guest synchronized to a single time source, the monotonic host time.

> The Oracle VM VirtualBox Guest Additions ensure that the guest's system time is synchronized with the host time.

同様の事象が再現できませんでしたので確認できていませんが、解決策として次のコマンドの実行がいくつかのサイトで提示されていました([参考](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313067/186949)):

```
sudo /usr/sbin/VBoxService --timesync-set-start
```

(また、Guest Additionsの再インストールで直りそうな気がしないでもないですが特に根拠はありません。)

---

時刻同期サービスを動作させる、という方策を採る場合は、
`/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.d/disable-with-time-daemon.conf` ファイルに

```
ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/VBoxService
```

という行があろうかと思いますので、これをコメントアウトするなりして実行しない条件から除外することになります。

---

参考として、冒頭の環境でのGuest Additionsインストール前後の実行結果を添付します:

Guest Additionsインストール前:

```
$ systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-04-05 18:57:34 JST; 2min 21s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
 Main PID: 335 (systemd-timesyn)
   Status: "Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.198:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com)."
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 1120)
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-timesyncd.service
           └─335 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd

 4月 05 18:57:34 yuki-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
 4月 05 18:57:34 yuki-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
 4月 05 18:58:06 yuki-VirtualBox systemd-timesyncd[335]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.198:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).


$ timedatectl 
                      Local time: 日 2020-04-05 19:05:10 JST
                  Universal time: 日 2020-04-05 10:05:10 UTC
                        RTC time: 日 2020-04-05 10:05:10
                       Time zone: Asia/Tokyo (JST, +0900)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Guest Additionsインストール後:

```
$ systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enab
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)


$ timedatectl 
                      Local time: 日 2020-04-05 19:58:51 JST
                  Universal time: 日 2020-04-05 10:58:51 UTC
                        RTC time: 日 2020-04-05 10:58:52
                       Time zone: Asia/Tokyo (JST, +0900)
       System clock synchronized: no
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Comment: sudo /usr/sbin/VBoxService --timesync-set-start　これで同期できました！

Comment: ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/VBoxService　これもコメントアウトしてみました。次回から再起動で自動的にこれが実行されるということなんでしょうか

Comment: 通常、Guest Additions をインストールすると `systemd-timesyncd` は不要になるので、起動しないようにする設定が `ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/VBoxService` という設定のようです( `VBoxService` が代わりに時刻同期する)。ですので、普通であればコメントアウトする必要は無いです。

Comment: そうなのですね。guest additions をもう１度いれてみます！　丁寧にありがとうございます

Answer (score 2):

NTPがネットワーク内に準備されている場合、NTPを使って時刻同期するのが普通でしょうが、仮想コンピュータの場合、ホストOSの時刻にゲストOSの時刻を同期させる方法があります。（NTPに同期させたい場合もあるので、任意にON/OFF可能）
Virtual Boxの場合マニュアルを参考に、有効化すればいいのではないかと思います。

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html

もうちょっと直接的な抜粋としては

https://digitalbox.jp/virtualbox-guest-sync-time-host/

そういうことじゃねーという話であれば申し訳ない。。
（内部で時刻同期の仕掛けを使っていることも考えられるので、systemd-timesyncd.serviceがfailっているのが直接の原因かもしれませんが。）

Comment: やってみたんですが特に変化なしです。ゲスト側の再起動もしてみましたが駄目でした。ホストの再起動も必要なんでしょうか

Comment: ところで「時計がずれている」というのはどういう意味ですか？
たとえば、今１９時なのに、OSの時刻は１０時とかそういう話ですか？
それとも、起動中に少しずつマシンタイムがずれるという意味ですか？
　⇒これってそんな簡単にずれてこないので試してから何時間も待たなくてはなりそうですが。。。前者なら別の問題。具体的になにをしたときに、なにとずれているのか　教えて下さい。

Comment: Local time: 日 2020-04-05 03:06:30 JST
           Universal time: 土 2020-04-04 18:06:30 UTC
                 RTC time: 土 2020-04-04 17:51:36　と書いた通りネットワーク同期してるwindowsホスト時刻 2:50 ぐらいに date コマンドの結果が 3:06 ぐらいになっていました

Comment: 土日に学校のプログラム課題やるときぐらいしかVM起動しないので少しずつずれたのかはよくわかりませんが、気づいたら１５分ほどずれてたので気になって質問した次第です。タイムゾーン的な９時間のずれではないです

Comment: あぁ、なるほど。解決されたとのこと。安心しました。

Answer (score 1):

`timedatectl` の結果で "RTC Time" が正しい時刻を指しているなら、[hwclock](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/ja/man8/hwclock.8.html) コマンドでシステムの時刻と同期を行ってみてください。

```
$ sudo hwclock             ## ハードウェア・クロックの確認
$ sudo hwclock --hctosys   ## ハードウェア・クロックをシステム・クロックに反映
```

Comment: １つ前の回答で治ってしまったので確認できないのですが、次に同じ症状が出たらやってみます！